# What is the probability of E given F in the image below

Tags: probability

[image]

I am unsure of my reasoning for both but here goes:

So for the one on the left, I get:

$$ P(E|F) = \frac{P(F)}{P(F)} = \frac{2/5}{2/5} = 1 \text{ ,since  } E\cap F = F$$

For the one on the right:

$$ P(E|F) = \frac{P(E)}{P(F)} = \frac{2/5}{5/5} = 2/5\text{  ,since } E\cap F =E $$

It seems that for the answer for the one on the right would give me 1 but the formulas don't conclude that. Is this correct? I am having difficulties seeing it.

Comment: In your formula, $P(EF)$ is not clearly defined.  It ought to be $E\cap F$.  Using that, for the left case we get $E\cap F = F$ so $1$ is correct (note:  your claim that, in that case $E\cup F=F$ is incorrect.) On the right, $E\cap F= E$ and $P(E)=\frac 26$. (again, your claim that $E \cup F = E$ is incorrect).

Comment: For the first you are expected to write $\dfrac{2/6}{2/6}$, which is $1$, and for the second $\dfrac{2/6}{5/6}$, which  is $2/5$.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'll correct the unions to intersections right away!